# Scala: Why does classOf[Int].cast(1) throw a java.lang.ClassCastException?

Tags: scala

When I run the following on the Scala 2.10 REPL:

```
classOf[Int].cast(1)
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to int
at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3176)
at .<init>(<console>:18)
...
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of *autoboxing*. It is a common feature, not only found in Scala, but also in Java.
The `int` value needs to be passed to the `cast` method as an object. But an `int` is not an object, so the compiler introduces a conversion to an instance of `java.lang.Integer`. And that's a different type than `int`, it's as simple as that.

This one should work:

```
classOf[java.lang.Integer].cast(1)
```